# Show files in online directory in ListView - Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

So basically I want to be able to view all the files that are stored in an online directory I have, mostly just images and textFiles.

Is that possible at all? And is the best way to accomplish that to use ListView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If by viewing the files you mean showing filenames and maybe some metadata, yes a ListView would be perfect. You can add a listener to download a file when it's clicked too.